# Как убедиться, что индекс в PostgreSQL создан

Tags: postgresql, index, liquibase

Есть БД из 3 таблиц: клиенты, счета и карты. У одного клиента может быть несколько счетов. К одному счёту может быть привязано несколько карт. Таблицы выглядят так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использую Liquibase для миграций БД. Написал changeLog для создания индексов:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">

    <changeSet id="Create indexes" author="Alex Td">
        <createIndex tableName="clients" indexName="index_fio">
            <column name="lastname"/>
            <column name="firstname"/>
            <column name="middlename"/>
        </createIndex>
        <createIndex tableName="accounts" indexName="index_client_id">
            <column name="client_id"/>
        </createIndex>
        <createIndex tableName="cards" indexName="index_account_id">
            <column name="account_id"/>
        </createIndex>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Далее делаю запрос на получение индексов, и вижу, что вроде как индексы появились в таблице **pg_indexes**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее для проверки запроса использую оператор EXPLAIN:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM clients
WHERE lastname = 'Иванов'
  AND firstname = 'Иван'
  AND middlename = 'Иванович';
```

Но результат такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

,если я правильно понимаю, этот результат (**Seq Scan on clients**) означает, что индекса нет. А если бы индекс был, то был бы результат типа такого:

```
Index Scan using index_fio on clients  (cost=... rows=... width=...)
   Index Cond: (active = ...)
```

Ну и аналогично для поиска карт по внешнему ключу (по индентификатору счёта). Сам запрос:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM cards
WHERE account_id = 4;
```

,а результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете пояснить: **у меня всё-таки добавились индексы, или нет? Почему запросы с оператором EXPLAIN их не отображают?**

Comment: И зачем postgresql использовать индекс если в таблице **одна** запись? Быстрее будет взять эту запись и проверить, чем найти что-то в индексе и пойти за записью.

Comment: Добавьте в таблицах минимум по несколько сот записей (с разными значениями конечно), сделайте analyze и потом уже смотрите планы выполнения. Оптимизатор гораздо умнее, чем просто "видим индекс - используем"

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо  @u_mulder , @Mike , получилось по вашим советам!

Сделал в таблице **клиенты** 300 записей, **счета** - 500 записей, **карточки** - 500 записей.

Далее опять пробую те же запросы, и теперь уже вижу что индексы используются:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и второй запрос:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Замените, пожалуйста, картинки текстовой информацией.